# Acess http://www.etymonline.com/ from terminal?

Tags: websites, dictionary

I haven't found some software to look up etymology of an English word from terminal yet.

If no available software doing that, how is it like to write a program connecting to www.etymonline.com/, making queries and parsing the webpages?
Thanks.

Comment: This is far too broad in its current form.  What exactly do you want to do on the site, and how far do you want to go with 'accessing' the site?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how far you want to go. Do you want to just fetch the web page for a word and view it on your browser? use wget like so: `wget http://etymonline.com/index.php?&search=cabbage` (notice substitution of search term). Do you want to then parse the web page and show only the text in the terminal? then it gets more complicated and you need to start looking at a concept called "screen scraping". By then, you're really looking at having to program this yourself, so in order to get adequate guidance you'd need to tell us about your profile, whether you're comfortable programming, which languages you know, and so on.

I guess a basic question is, why do you want to do this in the terminal and not on a browser?

Comment: Thanks. I just want to search the etymology of a word every now and then quickly and simply. I am lazy to open another firefox tab, and impatient to wait for the website turning up and for it searching for the word. I know programming in Python and C a little. If there is some package or example that I can follow, it will help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with Lynx and seem to work ok. Of course, you have to consider the UI limitations due to the use of a terminal instead of a browser.

In order to install lynx type:

```
sudo apt-get install lynx
```

In order to use it, e.g. with the web you wanted, type:

```
lynx www.etymonline.com
```

Note that you should browse the buttons with `TAB` key or with the mouse complement that comes with lynx. Check the lynx manpage (`man lynx`) for detailed info on how to use the program.

Cheers!